# Error al recibir HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND con restTemplate al consumir api

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un api en Spring Boot la cual consumo con otra aplicación en Spring, tengo un código el cual consulta un usuario y retorna el usuario o un mensaje JSON con su HttpStatus dependiendo si encuentra un usuario.

Cuando encuentra un usuario retorna Status OK y sirve perfecto mi cliente obtiene el usuario todo normal pero cuando el api retorna un 404 mi app cliente no valida el status y se salta a mi
`catch(Exception e)` y necesito validar en el status para mostrar un mensaje correcto al usuario final y no que entre al catch.

Código api.

```
// Consulta usuario por id
    @GetMapping(value = "/search/{id:[\\d]+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<Object> searchUser(@PathVariable long id) {
        UsuarioVO usvo = service.searchUser(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(usvo != null ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(usvo != null ? usvo : Util.messageJson("Este usuario no existe"));
    }

// Si no encuentra usuario el JSON ES ASI: { "message": "Este usuario no existe"} que seria lo que retorna el metodo --> Util.messageJson("Este usuario no existe") y el json esta bienn formado
```

Exception:

```
 ERROR AL CONSULTAR USUARIO:  org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : [{"message":"Este usuario no existe"}]
```

Mi Código cliente.

```
 private void consultarUsuario(@PathVariable long id) {
        try {

// Esta tam bien falla con el 404: String responsse =restTemplate.getForObject(laurl,String.class);

// --------------------
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(PATH_API_USERS + "/search/" + id, HttpMethod.GET, Util.getHttpEntity(), String.class);
// Si el status es OK SIGUE EL CODIGO Y SI EL STATUS ES 404 SALTA AL CATCH SIN  ENTRAR AL IF

            if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                // Mapea objeto JSON de UsuarioVO
                UsuarioVO usvo = objMap.readValue(response.getBody(), UsuarioVO.class);
                logger.info("Nombres: " + usvo.getUsnombres());
            } else if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
                logger.info("Sin informacion");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ERROR AL CONSULTAR USUARIO:  " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La única forma que tu catch no capture tu excepcion es porque o es un Error u otra excepción que herede de la clase Error o del padre de todas las excepciones Throwable. Prueba cambiando Exception por Throwable en tu catch y pon un breakpoint para que veas exactamente cuál es el error y puedas corregirlo. Una vez organizado devuelve el Throwable a Exception.

No sobra que mires el arbol de herencia de la excepciones [exception hierarchy](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_hierarchy.shtml)